# Entity Framework ORA-04098: Trigger Error

Tags: oracle, entity-framework

I have a trigger which updates the entries of another table while inserting one table. It is basically copy some of data to another table. I compiled is on toad and it worked successfully but when i try to insert a new values to table by using my web application entity framework throws an exception :

```
SQL Error: ORA-04098: trigger 'ExampleTrigger' is invalid and failed re-validation;
```

What should i do? I disabled the trigger and also droped it, tried again nothing is changed. Same error in related trigger.

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to the same database and schema in .Net as you are in TOAD?

Comment: @GriffeyDog Yes, totally.